# Checkboxes, javascript and php. Not loading results

Tags: php, javascript, checkbox, checked

I have a javascript code that reads from a set of checkboxes and loads a php in case one or more checkboxes are checked. This php will load only the items that are selected.

However, now I click on the checkboxes and nothing happens. I am not sure if the issue is in the php or in the javascript.

Here are the codes:

CHECKBOXES:

```
function echoCheckboxSet($header, $divClass, $columnName, $setName) {
include ("../commonItems/connection.php");
$checkboxes = $con -> prepare("SELECT DISTINCT $columnName FROM item_descr ORDER BY $columnName ASC");
$checkboxes->execute();
<?php
while ($box = $checkboxes->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):
$boxColumnName = str_replace('_',' ',$box[$columnName]);
?>
<input type='checkbox' class='regularCheckbox' name='<?php echo $setName; ?>' value='<?php echo $box[$columnName]; ?>' />
<font class='similarItemsText'><?php echo $boxColumnName; ?></font>
<br />
<?php
endwhile;
echoCheckBoxSet("COLOR", "colors", "color_base1", "color");
echoCheckBoxSet("PRICE", "prices", "price", "price");
?>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(function() {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function() {
        var boxes = [];
        // You could save a little time and space by doing this:
        var name = this.name;
        // critical change on next line
        $("input[type='checkbox'][name='"+this.name+"']:checked").each(function() {
            boxes.push(this.value);
        });
        if (boxes.length) {
            $(".loadingItems").fadeIn(300);
            // Change the name here as well
            $(".indexMain").load('indexMain.php?'+this.name+'=' + boxes.join("+"),
            function() {
                $(".indexMain").fadeIn('slow');
                $(".loadingItems").fadeOut(300);
            });

        } else {
            $(".loadingItems").fadeIn(300);
            $(".indexMain").load('indexMain.php', function() {
                $(".indexMain").fadeIn('slow');
                $(".loadingItems").fadeOut(300);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

INDEXMAIN (indexMain.php)

```
include('../commonItems/connection.php');
if ($colors != '')
 {

            $colors = explode(' ', $colors);
            $parameters = join(', ', array_fill(0, count($colors), '?'));
            $items = $con -> prepare("SELECT * FROM item_descr WHERE color_base1 IN ({$parameters})");
            $items ->execute($colors);
            $count = $items -> rowCount();

}
while($info = $items->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
......... echo everything....
```

At some point the code was working fine... but now it is not...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

indexMain.php is not getting the passed variables.

Adding this at the top made it work:

```
$colors = $_GET['color'];
```